# How to implement num2hex function based on first command line argument

Tags: go

Implemented the function `num2hex()` which takes an unsigned integer and returns its hexadecimal equivalent as a string. But here the function should take an extra argument `-u` which specifies whether the hexadecimal digits should be in lower case (default) or upper case.

eg: `677` outputs `2a5`

eg: `-u 107471` outputs `1A3CF`

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    //p := 107471

    //h := fmt.Sprintf("%x", p)

    p := os.Args[1:]

    var err error
    nums := make([]int, len(p))
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        if nums[i], err = strconv.Atoi(p[i]); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Not a number")
        }
        num2hex(nums[i])
    }
}

func num2hex(m int) {
    fmt.Printf("%x", m)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
package main

import (
   "flag"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   var upper bool
   flag.BoolVar(&upper, "u", false, "upper case")
   flag.Parse()
   for _, s := range flag.Args() {
      var n int
      fmt.Sscan(s, &n)
      if upper {
         fmt.Printf("%X\n", n)
      } else {
         fmt.Printf("%x\n", n)
      }
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/flag#BoolVar